# Auto populating the 31st day of a given month in excel

Tags: excel, if-statement, worksheet-function, auto-populate, data-entry

I am building a template for a data entry spreadsheet at work for some of the old-timers. The template that they will see will be columns of categories and the rows will be dates including the day of the week. I know how to auto-fill the date an day by drag and drop, but honestly some of these guys even screw that up. So, I am building this spreadsheet that auto populates the date and the day for the whole month based on entering the first day of the month that way its as simple as possible, but I am having trouble with the 31st day of some months. I don't want to have two different spreadsheets. Right now the code that I have is:

=EOMONTH(A5,0)

This works if it is the 31st day of the month, which is great, but if it is not a month that has 31 days it repeats the 30th day. I'd really like it to be an if statement, but I know my code is off because it always generates a FALSE.

Is =if(A5(M<2),"EOMONTH(A5,0)") heading in the right direction? It generates a #REF! reponse with that code.

Thank you for any input!

Comment: What is in **A5** ??

Comment: And I’m having trouble with “young-timers” who can’t do calcs in excel....

Comment: @Gary'sStudent A5 will be the date they enter manually each month before they print a new monthly sheet out, so it will always be the 1st of the month, then the rest of the cells below will calculate the rest of the days out by +1 to the previous cell.

Comment: @pnuts, A5 - open cell to be entered manually each month. Every cell below will calculate the next day by adding +1. All my cells through A34 are correct, but if there is no 31st this adds the first day of the next month in A35. I would like cell a35 to be blank if there is not a 31st day. Right now, I have a35 coded: 

=EOMONTH(A5,0)

This has a35 print a double 30th day if it is not a month with 31 days

Comment: @pnuts, your inital code worked! thank you! Now I am offf to try and get some of this data to copy and paste into specific cells on another workbook. Do you think that I will need VBA for this?

Answer (score 1):

In **A5** enter the date of the first day of the month.  In **A6** enter:

```
 =A5 + 1
```

and copy downwards.

In **A35** enter:

```
=IF(DAY(A34+1)=1,"",A34+1)
```

[image]

This assumes that you are making the date sequence by adding ***1*** to the cell above.

**EDIT#1:**

Put this in **A6**:

```
=IF(A5="","",IF(DAY(A5+1)<DAY(A5),"",A5+1))
```

and copy downwards through **A35**.

This will handle long months, short months, leap years, etc.

*(this also has the advantage of maintaining the same formula for the entire set of cells)*

Comment: Got it to work, but I realized that February is tricky now. I've got a33 and a34 working correctly, but now i have the need to check for two numbers on printing the 31st day, I can't remember the syntax. In java, I think its ...=28|30) or ....=28 & 30). Any thoughts?

Comment: @Jfwhyte8  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: thats awesome! thank you for all the help. you're right that solved everything!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add an `IFERROR` before the `IF` to fix the February problem:

```
=IFERROR(IF(DAY(A34+1)=1,"",A34+1),"")
```